# How to change Flyout ShellContent title text-color in MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui, flyout

Please look at my Flyout ShellContents image:

[image]

Just wondering, how can I change the text color of shellcontents in Flyout, as I can not find any appropriate foreground/text-color property under ShellContent to change the text color of the title. I have to apply the color from C#. I am making shellcontent pages as mentioned below:

```cs
ShellContent _ShellContent = new ShellContent
{
    Title = "Home", 
    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(HomePage)),
    //Route= "HomePage",
     
    Icon = new FontImageSource
    {
        Glyph = Application.Current.Resources["Font-Home"].ToString(),
        FontFamily = "MaterialFontFamily",
        Color = _ShellIconColor
    },
};
    
ShellPages.Items.Add(_ShellContent);
```

My AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="myProject.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myProject"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:myProject.Views" 
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout" x:Name="ShellPages"> 
        
</Shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Style FlyoutItem and MenuItem objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#style-flyoutitem-and-menuitem-objects), you can use `FlyoutItemLabelStyle` to change the text color of shellcontents in Flyout.

Please add below style to your `Styles.xaml` under **Resources\Styles** folder in your project.

```
<Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">

      <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"> </Setter>
        
</Style>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Not working for me. Also tried without setting the StyleClass explicit, as it should be set automatically.
<MenuItem
    Command="{Binding Expand}"
    StyleClass="{x:StaticResource FlyoutItemLabelStyle}"
    Text="Generelt">
    <MenuItem.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="FontAwesome"
            Glyph="{x:Static customRenderer:Icon.General}"
            Color="White" />
    </MenuItem.IconImageSource>
</MenuItem>

Comment: @Vering You can post a new thread and provide more details on this question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159208/maui-shell-how-to-change-color-of-text-in-flyout-item-menuitem-and-add-extra

Comment: @Vering Looks like this issue potentially happens on Android, you may need define the DataTemplate locally inside the "MenuItem" to fix it!