# Change text color in the AppShell in .NET Maui (.NET 8)

Tags: c#, android, maui, textcolor

I would like to change the text color in the AppShell. Under .NET 6 I had the following implementation in the Styles.xaml, which worked like this:

```
<Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle"
       TargetType="Label">

    <Setter Property="TextColor"
            Value="White"></Setter>

</Style>
```

See also the answer here: [How to change Flyout ShellContent title text-color in MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905681/how-to-change-flyout-shellcontent-title-text-color-in-maui)

After I upgraded the app to .NET 8, the adjustment of the text colour in the AppShell (under Android) no longer works. Does anyone have an idea how this can be solved?

[Screenshot Android AppShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pPNv.png)

I want to set FlyoutBackgroundColor to black and TextColor of labels to grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue about this problem, you can follow it up here: [[regression/8.0.3] FlyoutItem and MenuItem styles don't work](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18994).

But you can try the following workaround:

```
<Style TargetType="Label" Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```