# MAUI Shell how to change color of 'Text' in Flyout-item 'MenuItem' and add extra Icon

Tags: maui, flyout, maui-shell

In the AppShell.xml

```
<Shell 
    ...
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="#353535"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <MenuItem Command="{Binding ExpandCollapseHouseCommand}" Text="House">
       <MenuItem.IconImageSource>
          <FontImageSource
              FontFamily="FontAwesome"
              Glyph="{x:Static customRenderer:Icon.House}"
              Color="White" />
      </MenuItem.IconImageSource>
  </MenuItem>
  ...
</Shell>
```

With this MenuItem I try to mimic an "Expand/Collapse accordion" so that a click on it will show more items beneath it. I have two questions:

**Question 1**

I want the 'Text' and the 'Icon' to be white. Easy to change color of the icon, so thought that changing color of the text should be just as easy. In the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#style-flyoutitem-and-menuitem-objects

it states that

> Shell includes three style classes, which are automatically applied to FlyoutItem and MenuItem objects. The style class names are FlyoutItemLabelStyle, FlyoutItemImageStyle, and FlyoutItemLayoutStyle.

So I tried to insert

```
<Style TargetType="Label" Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

into my Resourses/Styles/Styles.xml, but that makes no difference. Also tried including it directly inside the <Shell.Resources>

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label" Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Furthermore, I tried added the StyleClass="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" property to the 'MenuItem' element, but nothing works.

Any help much appreciated.

**Question 2**

I need to add an indicator (aka an extra icon) to the MenuItem, to indicate whether it is expanded or collapsed. Natively, the MenuItem has only a 'Text' and one 'Icon' property. I know how to style this, but do not know how to add the extra icon.

Comment: Please include a single question per post only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem on the android. But on the windows platform, it worked well. So you can report this issue on the maui repo.

And you can [Define MenuItem appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#define-menuitem-appearance) to achieve the effect you want.

```
   <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="3*,4*,3*">
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       TextColor="Green"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="indicator.png" HeightRequest="45"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

And then declare the menuitem:

```
<MenuItem Text="Hello" IconImageSource="itemicon.png"/>
```

=================

Thanks for Vering's feed back: Declaring the `<Shell.MenuItemTemplate>` below the `<MenuItem>` will custom the special menuitem.

```
<MenuItem>
     <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="3*,4*,3*">
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       Source="icon.png"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       TextColor="Green"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="indicator.png" HeightRequest="45"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also just confirmed that the color works on iOS.

Comment: And thanks for template. However, I would need a new property "indicator", as I need to be able to change the state (switch the icon). So I need yet another icon to bind to.

Comment: You can try to bind the second iamge's source to change the icon, because you only have two states and only use two icons. @Vering

Comment: Again - thanks Zhang. However, I guess I would need a template for every instance of my 'accordion's. So say I have 3 'accordions', wouldn't I need 3 templates then? I could probably live with that, but it would be kind of contradictory calling it a template.

Comment: Did you mean you want every menuitem's indicator different? @Vering

Comment: Yes, you can expand/collapse them independently. So if expanded, I have the normal "arrow down" and if collapsed it will be "arrow down".

Comment: The only way I find can add new control in the menuitem is use the datatemplate. But it will apply for every menuitem. I also try to custom my own menuitem, but I failed because there is no control or layout in the menuitem's source code. So your requirement seems can't implement. @Vering

Comment: Hi @Zhang, seems like I can define the DataTemplate locally inside the "MenuItem" so that it is "scoped per MenuItem" and not shared
<MenuItem  Text="MyText">
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="MenuItem">
         ...
In this way I can define the template for each item separately. Thanks a lot for your help so far. If I get this to work I will post the solution. Maybe not the most pretty solution, but might be the only solution, and still it is simple.

Comment: You are welcome. I have tested it and this will applay for the special menuitem. And I have updated the answer. @Vering